# Jest doesn't work with util.promisify(setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-promise

I am aware there are a lot of similar questions on SO, but I believe mine is different and not answered by any of the current answers.

I am testing a REST API in Express.JS. Below is a minimal working example and several different numbered test cases.

```
const express = require("express");
let request = require("supertest");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const app = express();
request = request(app);
const timeOut = promisify(setTimeout);

const timeOut2 = time =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });

app.locals.message = "Original string";

app.get("/one", async (req, res) => {
  await timeOut(1000);
  res.send(app.locals.message);
});

app.get("/two", (req, res) => {
  res.send(app.locals.message);
});

app.get("/three", async (req, res) => {
  await timeOut2(1000);
  res.send(app.locals.message);
});

test("1. test promisify", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const response = await request.get("/one");
  expect(response.text).toEqual("Original string");
});

test("2. test promisify with fake timers", () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  request.get("/one").then(res => {
    expect(res.text).toEqual("Original string");
  });
  jest.runAllTimers();
});

test("3. test promisify with fake timers and returning pending promise", () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const response = request.get("/one").then(res => {
    expect(res.text).toEqual("Original string");
  });
  jest.runAllTimers();
  return response;
});

test("4. test no timeout", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const response = await request.get("/two");
  expect(response.text).toEqual("Original string");
});

test("5. test custom timeout", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const response = await request.get("/three");
  expect(response.text).toEqual("Original string");
});

test("6. test custom timeout with fake timers", () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const response = request.get("/three").then(res => {
    expect(res.text).toEqual("Original string");
  });
  jest.runAllTimers();
  return response;
});
```

Running the tests invividually shows that only test 5 passes.
My first question then is why does test 5 pass and not test 1, considering they are exactly the same test, other than a different implementation of the promise-based delay.
Both implementations work perfectly outside of Jest tests (tested using Supertest without Jest).

While test 5 does pass, it uses real timers so is not ideal. Test 6 should be the fake timer equivalent as far as I can see (I also tried a version with done() called inside the `then` body), yet this fails as well.

My web app has a route with a handler that uses `util.promisify(setTimeout)` so the fact that Jest falls on its face trying to test it, even with real timers, makes the framework much less useful to me. This seems to be a bug considering that a custom implementation (test 5) actually does work.

Nonetheless, Jest still doesn't work on test 6 with mock timers so even if I reimplement the delays in my app (which I don't want to do), I would still have to suffer slow tests that can't be sped up.

Are either of these issues expected behaviour? If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*why does test 5 pass and not test 1, considering they are exactly the same test*" - test 5 uses an `async` function and does return a promise to jest, it is more similar to test 3 than to test 1.

Comment: Yes, Jest not being able to mock a promisified `setTimeout` sounds like a bug. Or should we call it a feature of `promisify`?

Comment: @skyboyer Are you sure? async functions return promises without a return keyword, do they not? Note that none of the examples in the Jest docs use `return` when they have an async function.

Comment: @Bergi That's my mistake. I updated it in my editor but didn't copy the changes over here. 1 and 5 are now completely equivalent

Comment: @skyboyer Since I updated test 1, only test 2 is async without returning a promise. You're right that this is an error, and it was just in there to cover all my bases.

Comment: @raiksey, I've deleted my comments. as for `promisify` I wondering if it expected to work with `setTimeout` at all. [Docs says](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) `promisify` wraps sync function to return `Promise`. But `setTimeout` is not sync function.

Comment: @skyboyer In fact if you look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) for setTimeout, you see that the promisified version is directly referred to and example given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  It gets all the way down to the implementation of core built-in functions.

---

### Why does test 5 pass and not test 1

This took a while to chase down.

The [default test environment in `Jest` is `jsdom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) and `jsdom` provides [its own implementation for `setTimeout`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/7d0a7065fc58a527cc13183a733cac6c2fb0c491/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L266-L272).

Calling `promisify(setTimeout)` in the `jsdom` test environment returns the function created by running [this code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f121ac0dc457281b9ced4afec1cebe13f4d84048/lib/internal/util.js#L272-L300) on the `setTimeout` provided by `jsdom`.

In contrast, if `Jest` is running in the `node` test environment calling `promisify(setTimeout)` simply returns the [built-in `node` implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f121ac0dc457281b9ced4afec1cebe13f4d84048/lib/timers.js#L450-L454).

This simple test passes in the `node` test environment, but hangs in `jsdom`:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');

test('promisify(setTimeout)', () => {
  return promisify(setTimeout)(0).then(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

**Conclusion**: *The `promisify`-ed version of the `setTimeout` provided by `jsdom` doesn't work.*

Test 1 and test 5 both pass if run in the `node` test environment

---

## Test code that uses `promisify(setTimeout)` with Timer Mocks

It sounds like the real question is how to test code like this with [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html):

app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const app = express();
const timeOut = promisify(setTimeout);

app.locals.message = "Original string";

app.get("/one", async (req, res) => {
  await timeOut(10000);  // wait 10 seconds
  res.send(app.locals.message);
});

export default app;
```

This took a while to figure out, I'll walk through each part.

#### Mock `promisify(setTimeout)`

It is not possible to test code that uses `promisify(setTimeout)` using Timer Mocks without mocking `promisify(setTimeout)`:

- In the `jsdom` environment `promisify(setTimeout)` will hang.
- In the `node` environment `promisify(setTimeout)` will be [the implementation provided by `node`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f121ac0dc457281b9ced4afec1cebe13f4d84048/lib/timers.js#L450-L454) which doesn't call `setTimeout` so when [`jest.useFakeTimers` replaces the global `setTimeout`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/a1f3e2cda489e262bd0a258a51c99f6a76812e1e/packages/jest-util/src/fake_timers.js#L350) it won't have any effect.

`promisify(setTimeout)` [can be mocked](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) by creating the following `__mocks__/util.js`:

```js
const util = require.requireActual('util');  // get the real util

const realPromisify = util.promisify;  // capture the real promisify

util.promisify = (...args) => {
  if (args[0] === setTimeout) {  // return a mock if promisify(setTimeout)
    return time =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
      });
  }
  return realPromisify(...args);  // ...otherwise call the real promisify
}

module.exports = util;
```

Note that calling `jest.mock('util');` in the test [is required since `util` is a core Node module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules).

#### Call jest.runAllTimers() on an interval

As it turns out, `request.get` kicks off a whole process in `supertest` that uses the [JavaScript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop) and doesn't run anything until the current running message (the test) has completed.

This is problematic since `request.get` will eventually run `app.get` which will then call `await timeOut(10000);` which won't complete until `jest.runAllTimers` has been called.

Anything in the synchronous test will run *before* `request.get` does anything so if `jest.runAllTimers` is run during the test it won't have any effect on the later call to `await timeOut(10000);`.

The workaround for this issue is to set up an interval that periodically queues messages in the JavaScript Event Loop that call `jest.runAllTimers`.  When the message that calls `await timeOut(10000);` runs it will pause on that line, a message calling `jest.runAllTimers` will then run, and the message waiting for `await timeOut(10000);` will then be able to proceed and `request.get` will complete.

#### Capture setInterval and clearInterval

The last point to note is that `jest.useFakeTimers` [replaces the global timer functions](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/a1f3e2cda489e262bd0a258a51c99f6a76812e1e/packages/jest-util/src/fake_timers.js#L345-L350) including `setInterval` and `clearInterval` so in order to set up our interval and clear it we need to capture the real functions before calling `jest.useFakeTimers`.

---

With all that in mind, here is a working test for the app.js code listed above:

```js
jest.mock('util');  // core Node.js modules must be explicitly mocked

const supertest = require('supertest');
import app from './app';

const request = supertest(app);

const realSetInterval = setInterval;  // capture the real setInterval
const realClearInterval = clearInterval;  // capture the real clearInterval

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();  // use fake timers
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();  // restore real timers
});

test("test promisify(setTimeout) with fake timers", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);

  const interval = realSetInterval(() => {
    jest.runAllTimers();  // run all timers every 10ms
  }, 10);

  await request.get("/one").then(res => {
    realClearInterval(interval);  // cancel the interval
    expect(res.text).toEqual("Original string");  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Came from something unrelated but Jest hangs my tests after using `jest.useFakeTimers()`. I couldn't find out how to undo `jest.useFakeTimers()`. `jest.useRealTimers()` works!